# Unified Auditing in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, auditing

If anyone is familiar with the Unified Auditing in Oracle, is there a way to audit the executions of procedures or functions within a package?    I know you can audit the actual package execution, but can you get the name of the procedure of function within the package?   I do not see it in the UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL view.

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no way to audit individual functions or procedures within a package, because Oracle doesn't recognize them as independent objects in the data dictionary.

Comment: You can however collect this information in an approximate manner if these procedures take more than a second to execute, by querying `v$session` every second or by querying `v$active_session_history` (which has already done the 1 second polling for you) and look at `plsql_entry_object_id` and `plsql_entry_subprogram_id`. This can then be joined to `dba_procedures` to get the procedure/function within the package that was being executed. But because this is based on polling, it's useful mainly for performance analysis, not for auditing. For that you'd need to instrument your code.